# Circular definition of import alias 'theme'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to extend the theme of a third party private npm module. The project compiles successfully but I keep getting a typescript error `Circular definition of import alias 'externalTheme'`

Below is how I am extending the theme. This is working perfectly in the way that it is using both my theme and the external theme combined

```
import { externalTheme, ExternalThemeInterface } from 'external-npm-repo...'

import { colors, ColorsTypes } from './colors'

export const MyTheme: MyThemeInterface = {
    ...theme,
    colors,
}

export interface MyThemeInterface extends ExternalThemeInterface {
    colors: ColorsTypes
}
```

The error I am getting is referencing circular dependency with the externalTheme import, im not sure what this exactly means and havent found any clear references when researching.

These are my Typescript settings

```
        "allowJs": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "esnext"
```

Comment: I suspect that your dependency has the problem. It compiles because of `skipLibCheck`, which turns off type checking in dependencies. Wherever you are seeing the error isn't picking up that setting.

Comment: Could you tried to reproduce it in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)? Because without seing the different types it's impossible to determine which part causes the circular definition.

Answer (score 5):

another reason for this error is when importing from a dependency which has the same name as the current file

example:

```
// local/file/express.ts
import * as express from 'express'
```

to solve this issue, rename the local file 'express.ts' into 'another-name.ts'

Answer (score 2):

Circular dependencies (also known as cyclic dependencies) occur when two or more modules reference each other.

This could be a direct reference `(A -> B -> A):`
or indirect `(A -> B -> C -> A):`.

Create a file `webpack.config.js` and try adding the `circular-dependency-plugin` to your webpack configuration https://www.npmjs.com/package/circular-dependency-plugin. This should show the circular dependency in your code.

Your code looks like this type `(A -> B -> A):` So,
For simpler patterns, such as A -> B -> A, `refactoring` may be necessary. Perhaps the modules that live in B could be moved to A. Or, necessary code could be extracted to a C that both A and B reference. If the two modules perform similar behaviors, they could also be combined into a single module.